# Likegate issue with js fb api, dialog box getting popup blocked

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I use the following code for a likegate but the popup login dialog box is getting blocked. a friend of mine said I can do with fb subscribe event. has anyone done it with that? Unless there is a way to trick the box to open as display:page instead of popup.

Any help appreciated.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        var page_id = "XXX";

      if (response && response.authResponse) {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
        FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
          if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
            console.log("LIKE");
            $('#container_like').show();
          } else {
            console.log("NO LIKEY");
            $('#container_notlike').show();
          }
        });
      } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                console.log("LIKE");
                $('#container_like').show();
              } else {
                console.log("NO LIKEY");
                $('#container_notlike').show();
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log("NO LIKEY");
            $('#container_notlike').show();
          }
        }, {scope: 'user_likes'});
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Popup is getting blocked by what? A popup blocker you have installed, the browser?

Comment: Anything buddy. But I figured it out just now. PHP SDK is much easier and doesn't require user-side authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the PHP way, which is much better and easier... here is the code for all people out there trying :)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'XXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXX',
'cookie' => true
));
$sr = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
?>

<?php if ($sr['page']['liked']): ?>
<-- STUFF IF A FAN -->

<?php else: ?>
<-- STUFF IF NOT A FAN -->

<?php endif; ?>
```